# Antonym for Utilitarian

Tags: single-word-requests

I was thinking about the phrase *form over function* today. A person who values function over form I would call *utilitarian*.

What about the opposite, when someone values form over function? I could not think of an adjective to describe this quite as succinctly.

What is an adjective for someone who values elegance over utility? I suppose this might be an antonym for *utilitarian*.

Comment: As a side note, in my work with computer programming, we often use the mantra "form *follows* function" to keep uus focused on getting the underlying mechanics working properly before worrying about the user interface details.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, a utilitarian would count the beauty of something as part of its utility.

An "artist" or an "aesthete" would value form.

In philosophy, utilitarianism is a school of thought.  There are other schools of thought that are often contrasted with utilitarianism.

Answer (score 1):

Since such a person would be concerned only by appearance and not with function, I would describe them as being ***superficial***

> 2 a :  concerned only with the obvious or apparent :  shallow
>   b :  seen on the surface :  external
>   c :  presenting only an appearance without substance or significance
>   <sub><sup>[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superficial)</sup></sub>

Comment: **Utilitarian** seems to value function over form.  What about someone who valued them **equally?**

Comment: *Superficial* in the larger sense means interested only in obvious or surface details, and I think to say it is the opposite of utilitarian reflects a certain bias. One can appreciate beauty intellectually and scientifically, and to ignore that the human mind appreciates beauty suggests a different kind of superficiality, which reduces the value of all things to numerical comparisons.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent- That an excellent question, but what does it have to do with my answer or OP's question?

Comment: @choster- You have a truly dizzying intellect. "...interested in obvious or surface details" - Yes, they are interested in *what it looks like* not what it *does*.  They'd rather have something that looks nice but doesn't work than something that works but doesn't look nice-  I'd call that being superficial.

Comment: @choster- I really am lost on how the human mind's capacity for appreciating beauty either intellectually or scientifically (whatever that means) comes into play here.  I think even a full-on utilitarian would likely admit that something is beautiful, they just would be unlikely to choose it over something that was less beautiful but worked better or did more.  I imagine that *ceteris paribus* even a utilitarian would choose what they perceived to be the most beautiful of two objects.

Comment: @Jim Is it possible that the OP meant someone who prefers a thing for its intrinsic value and not for what it can do for you? At least, that's how I understood the question. Still looking for that word...

Comment: @Mary- I didn't think so.  OP says, "...values form over function" I'd think OP'd have said, "... values *value* (worth) over function" if intrinsic value was the differentiating parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Frivolous - not having serious value or purpose. While "superficial" could work, it may not work in all cases, as there can be utilitarian applications of something superficial (think: facades on buildings) but something frivolous has no purpose at all.